# Why it is necessary to add response delay to corrected received age in HTTP age calculation?

Tags: http, caching

[RFC 2616 Sec 13.2.3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.2.3) gives the following age calculation algorithm:

```
apparent_age = max(0, response_time - date_value);
corrected_received_age = max(apparent_age, age_value);
response_delay = response_time - request_time;
corrected_initial_age = corrected_received_age + response_delay;
resident_time = now - response_time;
current_age   = corrected_initial_age + resident_time; 

Where

age_value: is the value of Age: header received by the cache with this response.
date_value: is the value of the origin server's Date: header
request_time: is the (local) time when the cache made the request that resulted in this cached response
response_time: is the (local) time when the cache received the response
now: is the current (local) time
```

My question is, why it is necessary to add response_delay to corrected_initial_age?

My understanding is that response_time - date_value already include delays between the response was generated and was received, so if we add to that the response_delay then we are also including the time between the request was generated and received by the server.

For example if the client send the request at time 0 (request_time = 0) receives the response (with no Age header age_value = 0) at time 4 (response_time = 4) and date header is 2 (date_value = 2).

```
apparent_age = max(0, 4 - 2) = 2
corrected_received_age = max(2, 0) = 2
response_delay = 4 - 0 = 4
corrected_initial_age = 2 + 4 = 6
resident_time = 8 - 4 = 4
current_age = 6 + 4 = 10
```

Why we should add 4 to corrected_received_age if the aparent_age value seems to be correct? it is just to take into account any possible clock skew? Am I missing something?

Comment: Please check http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p6-cache-22.html#age.calculations and report back whether that clarifies things.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the reference. There, response_delay is only used to correct, when available, the age_value. it does not affect aparent_age. So, can we assume this is an errata in current RFC or an improvement to be corrected later? If you want to add this as an answer I will close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upcoming revision of RFC 2616 is going to tune that algorithm, see http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p6-cache-22.html#age.calculations for details.